# iframeを正規表現で判別する方法

Tags: php, html5, 正規表現

入力されたurlがgooglemapのiframeかどうかを判別するのは以下のコードであっていますか？

```
preg_match("/<iframe src=\"https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/map(.*?)<\/iframe>/s", $map, $is_map);

  if(!isset($is_map[1])){
    echo "地図の埋め込みコードが不適切です。";
  }else{
    echo "正しい地図です。";
 }
```

マップのurlを入力するシステムを作っているので、マップ以外のコードが入力された時に排除したいです。

Answer (score 0):

```
   preg_match("/<iframe src=\"https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/map(.*?)<\/iframe>/s", $map, $is_map);
```